# Computing sample variance

Tags: machine-learning, self-study, svm, kernel-trick

[image]

Anyone could help with this question on my homework?

I managed to substitute f into the expression, and express the denominator as a summation of kernels. However, I am not sure what should I do with the nominator of the linear algebra expression.

Answer (score 2):

Since it's self-study, I won't give you the full answer. But use the facts:

- The dot product is bilinear, namely for any scalar $\lambda$ and any two points $a,b\in\mathcal{X}$
  $$\langle \varphi(a)+\lambda\varphi(b),\varphi(x)\rangle = \langle \varphi(a),\varphi(x)\rangle + \lambda\langle \varphi(b),\varphi(x)\rangle$$
- The linearity generalizes to any finite sum with $n$ elements
- By definition you have $\langle \varphi(x_i),\varphi(x)\rangle = k(x_i,x)$

This should be enough to express the numerator in terms of $k(x_i,x)$, the denominator in terms of $k(x_i,x_j)$ and $f$ in terms of $\varphi(x_i)$.